I can't render fog

I was doing a skillshare course on blender. Its been a month since i started. Soo i dont know a lot of things. Please help me with my render!

Welcome to BSE
Please provide more information or a .blend file. Stack Exchange is not a website where you can simply ask for help without providing sufficient details.

Better yet, ( you appear to be attempting a volumetric material filling a cube )  simplify your file, say, with the cube on a simple floor-plane, and share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/.. that would make it quicker to find one of several slip-ups you might have made.
